# Saving JsObject into DynamoDB

Tags: json, scala, playframework, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

We want to save our data models into DynamoDB. We use scanamo with alpakka for nonblocking I/O. 
For numerous reasons, we don't want the keys and data to be auto generated to dynamo format. We already have Play-Json formatters for all our case classes and want the data to be saved in Dynamo from JsObjects.

For saving the data as JsObject, each repository has the following

```
import com.gu.scanamo.Table
val table = Table[JsObject](name)
```

Always end up receiving this error:

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.gu.scanamo.DynamoFormat[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]

I can't find a way to make it accept JsObject or create a formatter that will fit.
Will much appreciate any help.

Sidenote: I've looked at [PlayDynamo-Repo](https://github.com/lifeway/play-dynamodb) but they actually create the whole request from scratch and we'd like to use scanamo's API.

Comment: It should be difficult to provide one based on stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code which works just as expected. I cannot share the sub-functions but it should give the general idea.

```
implicit val dynamoFormat: DynamoFormat[JsValue] = new DynamoFormat[JsValue] {
    override def read(av: AttributeValue): Either[DynamoReadError, JsValue] = {
        Option(av.getS).map {
            fromStringAttributeValue
        } orElse Option(av.getN).map { n =>
            Right(JsNumber(BigDecimal.apply(n)))
        } orElse Option(av.getBOOL).map { b =>
            Right(JsBoolean(b))
        } orElse Option(av.isNULL).map { _ =>
            Right(JsNull)
        } orElse Option(av.getSS).map { ss =>
            Right(JsArray(ss.asScala.map(JsString.apply)))
        } orElse Option(av.getNS).map { ns =>
            Right(JsArray(ns.asScala.map(n => JsNumber(BigDecimal(n)))))
        } orElse Option(av.getL).map { l =>
            traverse(l.asScala.toList)(read).right.map(JsArray.apply)
        } orElse Option(av.getM).map { m =>
            traverse(m.asScala) {
                case (k, v) => read(v).right.map(j => k -> j)
            }.right.map(values => JsObject(values.toMap))
        } getOrElse {
            Left(YOUR_ERROR_HERE)
        }
    }

    override def write(t: JsValue): AttributeValue = {
        val res = new AttributeValue()
        t match {
            case JsNumber(n) => res.setN(n.toString())
            case JsBoolean(b) => res.setBOOL(b)
            case JsString(s) => res.setS(stringToAttributeValueString(s))
            case a: JsArray => res.setL(a.value.map(write).asJava)
            case o: JsObject => res.setM(o.value.mapValues(write).asJava)
            case JsNull => res.setNULL(true)
        }
        res
    }
}
```